# how to create a live-usb for ubuntu from a lubuntu system

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, iso

I am using lubuntu 12.04 on my PC. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. How do I create live-usb on Lubuntu so that I can install Ubuntu OS to my Laptop.

---

Edit: There's no startup disc creator in `Lubuntu Software Center`

Comment: try `unetbootin`

Comment: Note that the Lubuntu Software Center is a "work in progress". LSC for version 12.10 has the startup disc creator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To install Startup Disk Creator, run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: So I'm trying to do the same thing, I installed Startup Disk Creator, and ran it (I assume you're supposed to use the command `usb-creator-gtk`) and wasn't quite sure how it worked.  But I tried downloading Ubuntu to my internal drive, then ran the usb creator, now it has an option to put Ubuntu on the disk so I do that.  Then I try to boot from the hard drive, so I restart, boot from usb, and when I do it tells me that it failed and gives a prompt `boot:` and not matter what command I give it, it tells me that it couldn't find that drive and returns the prompt.  Any help you can give?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package usb-creator-gtk on 14.04

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) software.

In their [homepage](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) you will find an [Installation Guide](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#install), and a [Live-USB Creator Guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/unetbootin/wiki/guide)

To install it from terminal enter the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```